# Solace JS API..slow when message size is big

Tags: javascript, solace

We are developing using Solace JS API. In the web app we are subscribing to a topic and consuming messages flatbuffer (around 700 kb). For testing, after consumption we are just printing "message recieved". It seems we are not able to consume faster and messages get piled up. When we test with string for ex. "Hello World" we are able to consume everything and no pile up. 
So it seems the slow consumption problem is when the message size is large.

Any thoughts or suggestion to handle this? We are using the sample provided on Solace JS API website.

Answer (score 0):

There are two common causes for this.

**Network cannot keep up with message rate.**

Assuming that there is 1Gbps of bandwidth between your Solace router and the Javascript client, the maximum theoretical message rate is only 1,000,000,000 / (700,000 * 8) = 178 messages/second.

This assumes that there are no overheads such as TCP headers and that the network is not suffering from issues such as packet loss.

**CPU of browser cannot keep up with incoming message rate.**

Is any core of your CPU spiking up to 100% utilization?

Comment: I observed the pattern today, while subscribing to a single topic, the subscription rate is fine, but while subscribing multiple topics(in this case 2 ) within the same session(each topic with 10 msgs per sec), we see that the subscription rate is slow and we are loosing the messages.   Could you please suggest how to make my subscription rate to normal while subscribing to multiple topics.

Comment: What rate are you getting with one vs two topic subscription? Also, what is your network link speed, and is your CPU spiking up to 100% utilization?